# Git equivalent for the given svn status command?

Tags: git, svn

'svn status -v "." | grep ^[ ACMR] | (some regex to get only file names)'.

This command essentially gives a list of all files and folders. What would be the git equivalent for the above 'svn' command. The git command 'git ls-files' lists all the tracked files and not the folders in the directory.

Answer (score 2):

> `git ls-files` lists all the tracked files and not the folders in the directory.

Git tracks only *files*, not directories. More specifically, Git tracks the [*contents* of files and their *paths*](http://shafiulazam.com/gitbook/7_the_git_index.html). This design choice is precisely the reason why you [can't commit an empty directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/115983/26396).

Having said that, if you're looking to list all *tracked* files in your working directory, you can run:

```
git ls-files --full-name
```

where [`--full-name`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files#git-ls-files---full-name) tells Git to print the paths relative to the root directory of the repository.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to list *all* the files and folders, ls will do this.

```
ls --recursive | grep ....
```